# Name node is not displaying iwhen I hit JPS command

Tags: hadoop

17223 JobTracker
16897 DataNode
17518 Jps
17451 TaskTracker
17129 SecondaryNameNode
8571 FsShell

Name node is not displaying

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you are using the same user for starting all users, so If namenode is coming in the jps output, Probably namenode daemons might be got killed to not started properly. you may use the following command for ensuring namenode process running or not

```
ps aux | grep -i namenode
```

If not running you may need to format your namenode before starting hdfs service, stop all hdfs deamons using `stop-dfs.sh` script then format your namenode using the below command and start HDFS using the `start-dfs.sh` script.

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Go through the below SO post if you are hitting the below situation.

[Hadoop namenode needs to be formatted after every computer start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083114/hadoop-namenode-needs-to-be-formatted-after-every-computer-start/27083276#27083276)

Comment: thanks @mike, it was a typo, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to check *all* running JVMs on the host via 'jps',
you need to run the command as root. Otherwise, 'jps' will only show
JVMs running as your currently logged-in user.

Please see this link for more: 
 https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/1dlxmB_GVuU

Answer (score 0):

Should always check the logs.. :)