# Restarting NameNode in Hadoop Cluster without format

Tags: hadoop

Due to some reasons had to shut down my master node in cluster, as if we start the cluster again the namenode wont run unless we format it again, is their any solution to start name-node without formatting... Tried everything..
Start-all.sh or starting namenode/datanodes individually but Namenode wont start untill i format it again, How can i start Name-node without formatting.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you check the namenode logs for the reason for this issue. You dont have to format the namenode. It is a one time activity and you can stop, restart the namenode or the entire cluster as many times as you wish. The namenode metadata is stored in the disk. Can you tell us where the namenode metadata is getting stored, I mean the local directory path.

Comment: Seems similar to another question posted and this was answer which helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27083276/4939361

Answer (score 0):

Please post the log information.

In fact, it needn't format when you restart the hadoop. Because the HDFS meta information would be storage in the disk, if you format the namenode, the meta information will be lost.

You can try whether there is namenode process still exist when you stop the cluster, use the commond `ps -e|grep java`. If yes, kill it and start namenode again.

Comment: not restarting the Hadoop.. Restarting the system (Master Node Computer) itself